# Añadir valores a un array en python

Tags: python, array

yo estoy codificando para ingresar valores de un vector de la siguiente forma:

```
array=[]
n=3
for i in range(n):
   x=int(input("Valor: "))
   array.append(x)
```

Sin embargo, busqué pero no encontre otra forma mas optima de poder ingresar valores al array, vengo de programar mucho en c++ y estoy aprendiendo python, probe de esta forma:

```
array=[]
    n=3
    for i in range(n):
       A[i]=int(input("Valor: "))
```

Pero no es valido, ¿Existe una forma mas adecuada de introducir valores por teclado a un array?

Comment: No existe otra forma con Python a secas. Peculariedades del lenguaje. Hay que vivir con eso. Por otra parte, nunca màs tendras que escribir "for (i=0; i<lim; i++)". Pronto descubriras que con Python la vida es mucho más simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo te recomiendo usar `List Comprehensions` de la siguiente forma.

```
numeros = [input("Valor: ") for x in range(3)]
```

> En Python 2 la función `input` intenta convertir el resultado a una declaración de Python y si quieres obtener todo el resultado como string usa `raw_input`.
> En Python3 `raw_input` no existe y solo se usa `input` y te devuelve un `string`